# Python: Loop not exiting with "break"

Tags: python

I have this while loop that is testing to make sure the user inputs either 1, 2, or 3.  Once the user inputs 1, 2, or 3, the loop keeps going infinitely, i can't get out of it.

```
while True:
    try:
         filterselection = raw_input("Please select a filter (1, 2, or 3): ")
         if filterselection == "1" or filterselection == "2" or filterselection == "3":
              filterselection = int(filterselection)
              break

      else:
          print "Not a valid number try again!"
      except TypeError:
          print "Lol, that's not a number try again!"
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Your indentation seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: instead of the multiple `or`s you can use the `in` operator and say `if filterselection in ('1', '2', '3'):` .  for your health.

Comment: also, there's nowhere in here that a `TypeError` could occur.  Unless you wanted to change the `if` to say `if int(filter_selection) in  range(1,4):`

Answer (score 10):

Don't mix tabs and spaces!  Here is what I see when pasting your original code into an editor that displays whitespace characters:

[image]

The arrows are tabs and the dots are spaces, it is very important that you don't mix these because if you do the code that you see might not be what the Python interpreter sees.

Comment: +1: here's a good reference: ["You cannot safely mix tabs and spaces in Python."](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk)

Comment: What's the best way to make sure code is copied correctly from Geany into this site?  Because when I copied and pasted, everything looked all weird on here.

Comment: @Binka My guess is that everything looked weird because there was a mix of tabs and spaces in your code, some sites or programs will display tabs with the same width as 8 spaces, other with a width of 4 spaces.